# VBA --> Placing transparent picture on another transparent picture

Tags: excel, vba, image, transparency, transparent

After searching for quite a while, I still can't find the solution to this problem.

**Background:**
I'm trying to build a product configurator that step by step will show an image of the finished product depending on choices in the form.

The "overview" image will be a "background image" and images with transparent background that are placed on top of each others.

**My problem(s):**

1. If I insert 2 pictures in the same image box in the form, I seem to loose the transparency in the images. I will end up only seeing the last inserted image with a white background instead of it's transparent background.

**Additional info for later programming:**

2. I would like to be able to delete an already inserted image
3. I do not care if the images need to be png or gif
4. If this can not be done in a form, I'm open to have it done in the excel sheet, but the images needs to be placed exactly in the same position on the sheet, on top of each others.
5. `LoadPictureGDI` I have only used to try and insert an .png image into the form
   (I've tried with .gif images also, not using `LoadPictureGDI`, but with the same outcome as described in my problem above)

My code so far:

```
Sub Sample(var_ec_image)
    Select Case var_ec_image
        Case "ec_base": AddPicture ("ec_base")
    End Select
End Sub

Sub AddPicture(picname As String)
    ' print picture from selection of form
        image_box.Picture = LoadPictureGDI( _
                ThisWorkbook.Path & "\images\" & picname & ".png")
    ' print test image on top of first image
        image_box.Picture = LoadPictureGDI( _
                ThisWorkbook.Path & "\images\ec_tilt_upper_part.png")
End Sub
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, maybe the example's not representative of your actual code but if so, your first procedure could be replaced with a single line: `AddPicture (var_ec_image)`, or you could get rid of it and call `AddPicture` directly with the `var_ec_image` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

As you've discovered, Excel makes inserted images opaque (non-transparent) by default.

However, **you can choose a specific color to be transparent**.

---

## Manually set a Transparent Color

- Select the image, then click the `Format` tab on the ribbon.
- In the `Adjust` group click <kbd>Color</kbd>.
- Click <kbd>Set Transparent Color</kbd>.
- Click your picture, on the color that should be transparent.

[image]
 <sup>⤷ **Image source:** ["Why is one stack piece in the Stack Overflow logo slightly off?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198821/370758)</sup>

---

## Set Transparent Color with VBA

You can use the [`PictureFormat.TransparentBackground` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.pictureformat.transparentbackground) to set the transparent color programmatically.

**For example**, to make the **white** sections **transparent** of an image called "Picture 1":

```
Sub WhiteToTransparent()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 1")
        With .PictureFormat
            .TransparentBackground = True
            .TransparencyColor = vbWhite
        End With
        .Fill.Visible = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Example adapted from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.pictureformat.transparentbackground).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so sometimes the simplest solution is never thought of :)
This works for me as I only have 8 pictures to handle.

How this was solved:

In the userform i added one image control for each of the tranparent images, and also one image control for the "base image".

All the image controls are the same width and height, and placed on eachothers.
"BackStyle" of image controls are set to "Transparent".
In "Picture" I inserted the different (transparent) pictures.

I then "hide" or "show" the specific image control depending on the selections in the form.

```
    If machine_form.Image2.Visible = False Then
        machine_form.Image2.Visible = True
  Else
        machine_form.Image2.Visible = False
    End If
```

I do appriciate the help I got, and I guess there will be more questions ahead